# How to calculate the number of threads and loop count in jMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am not able to find out the specific answer of how to calculate the number of threads for running a load test in JMeter?
How to identify the loop count ?

Is there any formula?

What are the parameters to consider for the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Say if you want to fire 100 request to server with 2 tps. then your threas properties should be like below:

Number of threads(users) :2.
Ramp up period: 100
Loop count :50

Based on above example.Please find below explaination.

•   Number of Threads (N): Sets the number of threads the JMeter will use to execute our test plan. We must know that each thread will execute the whole test plan, which effectively utilizes the number of users that could use the tested service at any given time simultaneously.

•   Ramp-Up Period R: Specifies how much time (in seconds) it will take for JMeter to start all the threads (simultaneous user connections). If the number of users is 5 and the ramp-up time is 10 seconds, then each thread will be started in a 2 second delayed interval. We need to be careful when setting this value, because if the value is too high the first thread will already finish processing the whole test plan before the second thread will even begin. This is important because that would effectively reduce the number of concurrent users using the testing server application at any given time. But the ramp-up period also needs to be high enough to avoid starting all of the thread at a single time, which could overload the target application.

•   Loop Count (L): How many times each thread group will loop through all configured elements belonging to that thread group.

Hope it helps!